# How to horizontally stretch image in CSS and display it on HTML with 3 separate images

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a search bar where the middle stretches. I have three images: left.png, middle.png, and right.png

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vvrq3/)

I tried this code in the CSS:

```
.div1 {
    background-image:url('../images/searchbar_a_corner-left.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:15px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.div2 {
    background-image:url('../images/searchbar_a_corner-middle.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    width:15px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}  
.div3 {
    background-image:url('../images/searchbar_a_corner-right.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:15px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

And this in the HTML (which I think is the incorrect part):

```
<div class="div1">
    <img src="search-icon.svg" />
</div>

<div class="div2">
    <input id="search" type="text" />
</div>

<div class="div3"></div>
```

All that shows up is right.png.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the width on .div2 to "auto", and set "float: right" on .div3

See if this helps

Answer (score 0):

Remove the width:15px from .div2

```
.div2 {
    background-image:url('../images/searchbar_a_corner-middle.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

For illustration purpuses I added colors for the background of divs.

Here is the forked fiddle: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VYcsw/1/)

Comment: Please branch the original fiddle and use this in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're referencing your pictures incorrectly. Using all of your code, I just found some pictures to use as backgrounds for [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vvrq3/1/), which works perfectly!

`right.png` is not the only picture to show up, but I think your intention is for `middle.png` to span the entire search box background. If this is the case, remove `width:15px;` from `.div2`, as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vvrq3/2/).